# This tex file generates correct indentation in "Prefácio" and Chapter 1, but a reversed indentation in Chapter 2. Cannot guess why

Tags: latex, indentation, paragraph

This is the preamble and part of the tex file. The indentation is OK for "Prefácio" and  chapter 1 (only first line indented), but gets reveed (first line not indented, the following ones are all indented)for chapter 2. Can anyone help with this?
I have tried it in Overleaf, but got the same result and no error message that could address the problem.

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  pagesize,
  10pt,
  bibliography=totoc,% <-- changed
  numbers=noenddot, % <-- changed
  headings=normal, % <-- changed
  %DIV=9,
  twoside=false,
  %parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{trajan}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  %\usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  %\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts

\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
}


\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\cslentryspacingunit} % times entry-spacing
\setlength{\cslentryspacingunit}{\parskip}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1\relax
    \def\par{\hangindent=\cslhangindent\endgraf}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
 \setlength{\parskip}{#2\cslentryspacingunit}
 }%
 {} 


\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to fill pages

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
        \centering{
            \fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 
            Análise Crítica da Pesquisa Clínica\par
        }
            
        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering{\Large{Joaquim P. Brasil-Neto}}\\
        \vspace{\fill}
        \centering \large{2022}
\end{titlepage}
%\renewcommand*\contentsname{Análise Crítica de Ensaios Clínicos}


%=========================================
\newpage
%\begin{fichacatalografica}

 %   \includepdf{images/ficha.pdf}

%\end{fichacatalografica}
%\
\newpage
\thispagestyle {empty}

\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{center}
    \Large{\parbox{10cm}{
        \begin{raggedright}
        {\Large 
            \textit{Half of what you'll learn in medical school will be shown to be either dead wrong or out of date within five years of your graduation; the trouble is that nobody can tell you which half- so the most important thing to learn is how to learn on your own.
}
        }
    
        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---David Sackett}
        \end{raggedright}
    }
}
\end{center}

\newpage
\
\newpage

\chapter{Prefácio}

Este livro foi escrito durante um semestre, enquanto o autor ministrava uma disciplina sobre análise crítica da pesquisa clínica. Essa disciplina é a última de uma série de oito dedicadas à medicina baseada em evidências e ministradas durante os quatro primeiros anos do curso de graduação em Medicina do Centro Universitário Euro-Americano, Unieuro, em Brasília-DF. Apesar de ter a sua origem em um curso de Medicina, os pontos aqui abordados também são de interesse para outros profissionais da área da saúde.

Atualmente, os profissionais da saúde são expostos a uma grande quantidade de informações e sugestões terapêuticas, sob a forma de palestras, artigos de revisão, consensos de especialistas, publicações patrocinadas pela indústria, dentre outras. Assim sendo, é da máxima importância que esses profissionais disponham de conhecimento suficiente sobre medicina baseada em evidências para que possam, com critérios científicos, selecionar a informação de qualidade que irá orientar a sua prática diária com os pacientes.

Esta obra aborda os erros mais comuns cometidos na pesquisa clínica, e indica como detectá-los ou mesmo evitá-los, no caso em que o profissional for o próprio pesquisador. Seguindo a mesma dinâmica do curso no qual se baseou, ela traz também atividades (``exercícios''), sob a forma de clubes de revista (\emph{Journal Clubs}), num total de sete. Para cada um, foram selecionados artigos publicados que ilustram conceitos importantes abordados nos capítulos precedentes.

A prática da medicina com base em evidências científicas sólidas é um ideal que todos devem procurar alcançar, mas para isso é necessária uma preparação intensiva desde a graduação. A adoção das metodologias ativas pelas atuais escolas médicas em nosso país tem o mérito de incentivar o espírito crítico e a busca ativa do conhecimento.

Este trabalho também pode servir de arcabouço para o planejamento de outros cursos que pretendam abordar o mesmo tema. Temos consciência de que nem todos os pontos importantes da matéria foram abordados e que alguns dos temas contemplados poderiam ter sido mais profundamente explorados. Entretanto, esses são problemas inerentes a qualquer curso que tenha uma carga horária pré-determinada, o que invariavelmente leva o docente a fazer escolhas pessoais sobre o que seria mais importante incluir.

Espero que este texto seja de utilidade para os profissionais de saúde durante suas explorações da ``selva'' da literatura biomédica atual. Em especial, desejo que seja de valia e que contribua para o sucesso profissional dos meus estudantes do Unieuro.

\vspace{5mm}

Brasília, DF, 25 de novembro de 2022


\tableofcontents


\frontmatter


\mainmatter

\chapter{Medicina Baseada em Evidências na Atualidade}
%\hypertarget{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas-na-pruxe1tica-muxe9dica}{%
\section{Desafios da Prática Médica Baseada em Evidências}\label{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas-na-pruxe1tica-muxe9dica}

A medicina foi praticada, durante séculos, mais como arte do que como ciência. Uma longa estrada foi trilhada desde os tratamentos supersticiosos, mágico-religiosos e empiricos até os nossos dias, em que cada vez mais se preconiza a prática médica baseada em evidências científicas.

Mas onde e como buscar as evidências científicas? O profissional de saúde de nossos dias é continuamente exposto a informações supostamente científicas, oriundas das mais diversas fontes: notícias veiculadas em jornais e na televisão, resultados publicados em periódicos de boa reputação, artigos publicados pelas indústrias farmacêuticas na internet, dentre outras. Entretanto, nenhuma fonte merece total confiança do profissional de saúde, que deve necessariamente fazer a sua análise crítica de todas as informações que recebe, não importa a origem ou suposta autoridade do veículo de divulgação.



%\hypertarget{referuxeancias}{%
\subsection*{Referências}\label{referuxeancias}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Referências}

%\hypertarget{refs}{}
\begin{CSLReferences}{1}{0}
\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-evansavaliaccao}{}}%
Evans, Imogen, Hazel Thornton, and Iain Chalmers. 2016. {``Avaliação de Tratamentos de Saúde,''} no. 2º Ed. \url{https://pt.testingtreatments.org/}.
\chapter{As Evidências Científicas na Medicina}
\hypertarget{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas}{%
\section{A importância das evidências científicas}\label{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas}}

A história do tratamento de diversas doenças revela a importância do uso das melhores evidências na tomada de decisões terapêuticas. A seguir descrevemos alguns casos ilustrativos (Evans, Thornton, and Chalmers 2016).

\hypertarget{o-escorbuto-e-o-primeiro-ensaio-cluxednico-controlado}{%
\subsection{O escorbuto e o primeiro ensaio clínico controlado}\label{o-escorbuto-e-o-primeiro-ensaio-cluxednico-controlado}}

O escorbuto matou mais de dois milhões de marinheiros nos anos decorridos entre a viagem transatlântica de Cristóvão Colombo e o aparecimento dos motores a vapor em meados do século XIX. O risco de morrer de escorbuto nos navios era tão grande que os governos já contavam com uma perda de pelo menos 50\% das tripulações em todas as viagens.

James Lind, um médico escocês que serviu como cirurgião naval no navio \emph{HMS Salisbury} em 1747 é frequentemente lembrado como o autor de um dos primeiros experimentos controlados do mundo. Ele utilizou 12 marinheiros com escorbuto como sujeitos experimentais, dividindo-os em 6 grupos de 2 doentes cada. Ele então os manteve no mesmo compartimento do navio, com todas as condições iguais exceto pelo tratamento. Cada par recebia a cada dia os tratamentos considerados potencialmente válidos na época: 290 ml de cidra, 25 gotas de vitriol, 2 colheres de sopa de vinagre, 235 ml de água do mar, nós-moscada ou um ``tratamento'' com 2 laranjas e 1 limão. O vitriol, à base de ácido sulfúrico, era recomendado pelo \emph{Royal College of Physicians} e o almirantado apostava no vinagre.

Lind manteve os tratamentos por 14 dias, exceto para a dupla que recebia os limões e laranjas, pois estes acabaram em uma semana. Não obstante, esses dois pacientes se recuperaram tão rapidamente que passaram a ajudar Lind a cuidar dos demais. Hoje nós sabemos que o escorbuto é causado por deficiência de vitamina C e que a suplementação alimentar com frutas cítricas foi curativa. Lind, entretanto, não se deu conta da importância do seu achado, e embora acreditasse que o suco de limão era eficaz ficou com dúvidas quanto ao efeito da cidra, que também resultou em algum grau de melhora (provavelmente a cidra pouco elaborada que foi utilizada continha alguma quantidade de vitamina C).

Este é um bom exemplo de como a opinião de autoridades (no caso o \emph{Royal College of Physicians} e o almirantado) pode não indicar o melhor tratamento para uma doença, sendo necessária a comprovação científica por estudos controlados e sem viés do pesquisador.

\hypertarget{riscos-dos-tratamentos-intuitivos-mas-sem-comprovauxe7uxe3o-cientuxedfica}{%
\subsection{Riscos dos tratamentos intuitivos mas sem comprovação científica}\label{riscos-dos-tratamentos-intuitivos-mas-sem-comprovauxe7uxe3o-cientuxedfica}}

Nos anos 40, a mortalidade infantil era tal que um de cada cinco bebês prematuros morria. Depois que os médicos perceberam que esses bebês tinham grandes dificuldades respiratórias, passaram a aumentar os níveis de oxigênio nas incubadoras (Evans, Thornton, and Chalmers 2016).

De 1942 a 1954 foi relatada uma ``epidemia'' de cegueira em recém-nascidos prematuros devido a uma condição conhecida como \emph{fibroplasia retrolenticular}, ou retinopatia dos prematuros. A causa da condição era desconhecida.



\hypertarget{referuxeancias}{%
\subsection*{Referências}\label{referuxeancias}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Referências}

\hypertarget{refs}{}
\begin{CSLReferences}{1}{0}
\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-evansavaliaccao}{}}%
Evans, Imogen, Hazel Thornton, and Iain Chalmers. 2016. {``Avaliação de Tratamentos de Saúde,''} no. 2º Ed. \url{https://pt.testingtreatments.org/}.

\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-mannMotherKissCan2012}{}}%
Mann, Denise. 2012. {``{`Mother's Kiss'} Can Expel Objects From Kids' Noses.''} WebMD. 2012. \url{https://www.webmd.com/children/news/20121015/mothers-kiss-expel-foreign-objects-kids-noses}.

\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-moschinoCaffeinePretermInfants2020}{}}%
Moschino, Laura, Sanja Zivanovic, Caroline Hartley, Daniele Trevisanuto, Eugenio Baraldi, and Charles Christoph Roehr. 2020. {``Caffeine in Preterm Infants: Where Are We in 2020?''} \emph{ERJ Open Research} 6 (1). \url{https://doi.org/10.1183/23120541.00330-2019}.

\end{CSLReferences}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a `CSLReferences` environment in l. 179 which you never close:

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  pagesize,
  10pt,
  bibliography=totoc,% <-- changed
  numbers=noenddot, % <-- changed
  headings=normal, % <-- changed
  %DIV=9,
  twoside=false,
  %parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{trajan}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  %\usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  %\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts

\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
}


\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\cslentryspacingunit} % times entry-spacing
\setlength{\cslentryspacingunit}{\parskip}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1\relax
    \def\par{\hangindent=\cslhangindent\endgraf}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
 \setlength{\parskip}{#2\cslentryspacingunit}
 }%
 {} 


\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to fill pages

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
        \centering{
            \fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 
            Análise Crítica da Pesquisa Clínica\par
        }
            
        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering{\Large{Joaquim P. Brasil-Neto}}\\
        \vspace{\fill}
        \centering \large{2022}
\end{titlepage}
%\renewcommand*\contentsname{Análise Crítica de Ensaios Clínicos}


%=========================================
\newpage
%\begin{fichacatalografica}

 %   \includepdf{images/ficha.pdf}

%\end{fichacatalografica}
%\
\newpage
\thispagestyle {empty}

\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{center}
    \Large{\parbox{10cm}{
        \begin{raggedright}
        {\Large 
            \textit{Half of what you'll learn in medical school will be shown to be either dead wrong or out of date within five years of your graduation; the trouble is that nobody can tell you which half- so the most important thing to learn is how to learn on your own.
}
        }
    
        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---David Sackett}
        \end{raggedright}
    }
}
\end{center}

\newpage
\
\newpage

\chapter{Prefácio}

Este livro foi escrito durante um semestre, enquanto o autor ministrava uma disciplina sobre análise crítica da pesquisa clínica. Essa disciplina é a última de uma série de oito dedicadas à medicina baseada em evidências e ministradas durante os quatro primeiros anos do curso de graduação em Medicina do Centro Universitário Euro-Americano, Unieuro, em Brasília-DF. Apesar de ter a sua origem em um curso de Medicina, os pontos aqui abordados também são de interesse para outros profissionais da área da saúde.

Atualmente, os profissionais da saúde são expostos a uma grande quantidade de informações e sugestões terapêuticas, sob a forma de palestras, artigos de revisão, consensos de especialistas, publicações patrocinadas pela indústria, dentre outras. Assim sendo, é da máxima importância que esses profissionais disponham de conhecimento suficiente sobre medicina baseada em evidências para que possam, com critérios científicos, selecionar a informação de qualidade que irá orientar a sua prática diária com os pacientes.

Esta obra aborda os erros mais comuns cometidos na pesquisa clínica, e indica como detectá-los ou mesmo evitá-los, no caso em que o profissional for o próprio pesquisador. Seguindo a mesma dinâmica do curso no qual se baseou, ela traz também atividades (``exercícios''), sob a forma de clubes de revista (\emph{Journal Clubs}), num total de sete. Para cada um, foram selecionados artigos publicados que ilustram conceitos importantes abordados nos capítulos precedentes.

A prática da medicina com base em evidências científicas sólidas é um ideal que todos devem procurar alcançar, mas para isso é necessária uma preparação intensiva desde a graduação. A adoção das metodologias ativas pelas atuais escolas médicas em nosso país tem o mérito de incentivar o espírito crítico e a busca ativa do conhecimento.

Este trabalho também pode servir de arcabouço para o planejamento de outros cursos que pretendam abordar o mesmo tema. Temos consciência de que nem todos os pontos importantes da matéria foram abordados e que alguns dos temas contemplados poderiam ter sido mais profundamente explorados. Entretanto, esses são problemas inerentes a qualquer curso que tenha uma carga horária pré-determinada, o que invariavelmente leva o docente a fazer escolhas pessoais sobre o que seria mais importante incluir.

Espero que este texto seja de utilidade para os profissionais de saúde durante suas explorações da ``selva'' da literatura biomédica atual. Em especial, desejo que seja de valia e que contribua para o sucesso profissional dos meus estudantes do Unieuro.

\vspace{5mm}

Brasília, DF, 25 de novembro de 2022


\tableofcontents


\frontmatter


\mainmatter

\chapter{Medicina Baseada em Evidências na Atualidade}
%\hypertarget{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas-na-pruxe1tica-muxe9dica}{%
\section{Desafios da Prática Médica Baseada em Evidências}\label{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas-na-pruxe1tica-muxe9dica}

A medicina foi praticada, durante séculos, mais como arte do que como ciência. Uma longa estrada foi trilhada desde os tratamentos supersticiosos, mágico-religiosos e empiricos até os nossos dias, em que cada vez mais se preconiza a prática médica baseada em evidências científicas.

Mas onde e como buscar as evidências científicas? O profissional de saúde de nossos dias é continuamente exposto a informações supostamente científicas, oriundas das mais diversas fontes: notícias veiculadas em jornais e na televisão, resultados publicados em periódicos de boa reputação, artigos publicados pelas indústrias farmacêuticas na internet, dentre outras. Entretanto, nenhuma fonte merece total confiança do profissional de saúde, que deve necessariamente fazer a sua análise crítica de todas as informações que recebe, não importa a origem ou suposta autoridade do veículo de divulgação.



%\hypertarget{referuxeancias}{%
\subsection*{Referências}\label{referuxeancias}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Referências}

%\hypertarget{refs}{}
\begin{CSLReferences}{1}{0}
\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-evansavaliaccao}{}}%
Evans, Imogen, Hazel Thornton, and Iain Chalmers. 2016. {``Avaliação de Tratamentos de Saúde,''} no. 2º Ed. \url{https://pt.testingtreatments.org/}.
\end{CSLReferences}
\chapter{As Evidências Científicas na Medicina}
\hypertarget{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas}{%
\section{A importância das evidências científicas}\label{a-importuxe2ncia-das-eviduxeancias-cientuxedficas}}

A história do tratamento de diversas doenças revela a importância do uso das melhores evidências na tomada de decisões terapêuticas. A seguir descrevemos alguns casos ilustrativos (Evans, Thornton, and Chalmers 2016).

\hypertarget{o-escorbuto-e-o-primeiro-ensaio-cluxednico-controlado}{%
\subsection{O escorbuto e o primeiro ensaio clínico controlado}\label{o-escorbuto-e-o-primeiro-ensaio-cluxednico-controlado}}

O escorbuto matou mais de dois milhões de marinheiros nos anos decorridos entre a viagem transatlântica de Cristóvão Colombo e o aparecimento dos motores a vapor em meados do século XIX. O risco de morrer de escorbuto nos navios era tão grande que os governos já contavam com uma perda de pelo menos 50\% das tripulações em todas as viagens.

James Lind, um médico escocês que serviu como cirurgião naval no navio \emph{HMS Salisbury} em 1747 é frequentemente lembrado como o autor de um dos primeiros experimentos controlados do mundo. Ele utilizou 12 marinheiros com escorbuto como sujeitos experimentais, dividindo-os em 6 grupos de 2 doentes cada. Ele então os manteve no mesmo compartimento do navio, com todas as condições iguais exceto pelo tratamento. Cada par recebia a cada dia os tratamentos considerados potencialmente válidos na época: 290 ml de cidra, 25 gotas de vitriol, 2 colheres de sopa de vinagre, 235 ml de água do mar, nós-moscada ou um ``tratamento'' com 2 laranjas e 1 limão. O vitriol, à base de ácido sulfúrico, era recomendado pelo \emph{Royal College of Physicians} e o almirantado apostava no vinagre.

Lind manteve os tratamentos por 14 dias, exceto para a dupla que recebia os limões e laranjas, pois estes acabaram em uma semana. Não obstante, esses dois pacientes se recuperaram tão rapidamente que passaram a ajudar Lind a cuidar dos demais. Hoje nós sabemos que o escorbuto é causado por deficiência de vitamina C e que a suplementação alimentar com frutas cítricas foi curativa. Lind, entretanto, não se deu conta da importância do seu achado, e embora acreditasse que o suco de limão era eficaz ficou com dúvidas quanto ao efeito da cidra, que também resultou em algum grau de melhora (provavelmente a cidra pouco elaborada que foi utilizada continha alguma quantidade de vitamina C).

Este é um bom exemplo de como a opinião de autoridades (no caso o \emph{Royal College of Physicians} e o almirantado) pode não indicar o melhor tratamento para uma doença, sendo necessária a comprovação científica por estudos controlados e sem viés do pesquisador.

\hypertarget{riscos-dos-tratamentos-intuitivos-mas-sem-comprovauxe7uxe3o-cientuxedfica}{%
\subsection{Riscos dos tratamentos intuitivos mas sem comprovação científica}\label{riscos-dos-tratamentos-intuitivos-mas-sem-comprovauxe7uxe3o-cientuxedfica}}

Nos anos 40, a mortalidade infantil era tal que um de cada cinco bebês prematuros morria. Depois que os médicos perceberam que esses bebês tinham grandes dificuldades respiratórias, passaram a aumentar os níveis de oxigênio nas incubadoras (Evans, Thornton, and Chalmers 2016).

De 1942 a 1954 foi relatada uma ``epidemia'' de cegueira em recém-nascidos prematuros devido a uma condição conhecida como \emph{fibroplasia retrolenticular}, ou retinopatia dos prematuros. A causa da condição era desconhecida.



\hypertarget{referuxeancias}{%
\subsection*{Referências}\label{referuxeancias}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Referências}

\hypertarget{refs}{}
\begin{CSLReferences}{1}{0}
\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-evansavaliaccao}{}}%
Evans, Imogen, Hazel Thornton, and Iain Chalmers. 2016. {``Avaliação de Tratamentos de Saúde,''} no. 2º Ed. \url{https://pt.testingtreatments.org/}.

\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-mannMotherKissCan2012}{}}%
Mann, Denise. 2012. {``{`Mother's Kiss'} Can Expel Objects From Kids' Noses.''} WebMD. 2012. \url{https://www.webmd.com/children/news/20121015/mothers-kiss-expel-foreign-objects-kids-noses}.

\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-moschinoCaffeinePretermInfants2020}{}}%
Moschino, Laura, Sanja Zivanovic, Caroline Hartley, Daniele Trevisanuto, Eugenio Baraldi, and Charles Christoph Roehr. 2020. {``Caffeine in Preterm Infants: Where Are We in 2020?''} \emph{ERJ Open Research} 6 (1). \url{https://doi.org/10.1183/23120541.00330-2019}.

\end{CSLReferences}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks!